# Delete all data for a kind in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to wipe out all data for a specific kind in Google App Engine. What is the
best way to do this?
I wrote a delete script (hack), but since there is so much data is
timeout's out after a few hundred records.

Comment: its a pain in the neck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official answer](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/ec0800a3ca92fe69#) from Google is that you have to delete in chunks spread over multiple requests. You can use AJAX, [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), or request your URL from a script until there are no entities left.

Answer (score 28):

I am currently deleting the entities by their key, and it seems to be faster.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class bulkdelete(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        try:
            while True:
                q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM MyModel")
                assert q.count()
                db.delete(q.fetch(200))
                time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception, e:
            self.response.out.write(repr(e)+'\n')
            pass
```

from the terminal, I run curl -N http://...

Comment: For me, it returns "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." instead of exception, but works :)

Comment: The code above breaks the loop by throwing an AssertionError and catching it. That's pretty ugly! Should just break if q.count() is 0

Answer (score 22):

You can now use the Datastore Admin for that: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk

Comment: A blog post warning you about the inefficiencies of Datastore Admin: http://marram.posterous.com/google-app-engines-datastore-admin-is-terribl

Comment: above link is dead, but I can add that bulk deletion of entities is not working for me at the moment (it goes through the motions and gives a successfully deleted message, but all entities remain).

Answer (score 10):

Presumably your hack was something like this:

```
# Deleting all messages older than "earliest_date"
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE create_date < :1", earliest_date)
results = q.fetch(1000)

while results:
    db.delete(results)
    results = q.fetch(1000, len(results))
```

As you say, if there's sufficient data, you're going to hit the request timeout before it gets through all the records. You'd have to re-invoke this request multiple times from outside to ensure all the data was erased; easy enough to do, but hardly ideal.

The admin console doesn't seem to offer any help, as (from my own experience with it), it seems to only allow entities of a given type to be listed and then deleted on a page-by-page basis.

When testing, I've had to purge my database on startup to get rid of existing data.

I would infer from this that Google operates on the principle that disk is cheap, and so data is typically orphaned (indexes to redundant data replaced), rather than deleted. Given there's a fixed amount of data available to each app at the moment (0.5 GB), that's not much help for non-Google App Engine users.

Comment: `db.delete` is synchronous so it is not necessary to provide offset to `q.fetch`.

Answer (score 10):

If I were a paranoid person, I would say Google App Engine (GAE) has not made it easy for us to remove data if we want to. I am going to skip discussion on index sizes and how they translate a 6 GB of data to 35 GB of storage (being billed for). That's another story, but they do have ways to work around that - limit number of properties to create index on (automatically generated indexes) et cetera.

The reason I decided to write this post is that I need to "nuke" all my Kinds in a sandbox. I read about it and finally came up with this code:

```
package com.intillium.formshnuker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;

import com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.QueueFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Method;

import static com.google.appengine.api.labs.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.url;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FormsnukerServlet extends HttpServlet {

 public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

  response.setContentType("text/plain");

  final String kind = request.getParameter("kind");
  final String passcode = request.getParameter("passcode");

  if (kind == null) {
   throw new NullPointerException();
  }

  if (passcode == null) {
   throw new NullPointerException();
  }

  if (!passcode.equals("LONGSECRETCODE")) {
   response.getWriter().println("BAD PASSCODE!");
   return;
  }

  System.err.println("*** deleting entities form " + kind);

  final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

  int deleted_count = 0;
  boolean is_finished = false;

  final DatastoreService dss = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

  while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 16384) {

   final Query query = new Query(kind);

   query.setKeysOnly();

   final ArrayList<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();

   for (final Entity entity: dss.prepare(query).asIterable(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(128))) {
    keys.add(entity.getKey());
   }

   keys.trimToSize();

   if (keys.size() == 0) {
    is_finished = true;
    break;
   }

   while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 16384) {

    try {

     dss.delete(keys);

     deleted_count += keys.size();

     break;

    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

     continue;

    }

   }

  }

  System.err.println("*** deleted " + deleted_count + " entities form " + kind);

  if (is_finished) {

   System.err.println("*** deletion job for " + kind + " is completed.");

  } else {

   final int taskcount;

   final String tcs = request.getParameter("taskcount");

   if (tcs == null) {
    taskcount = 0;
   } else {
    taskcount = Integer.parseInt(tcs) + 1;
   }

   QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(
    url("/formsnuker?kind=" + kind + "&passcode=LONGSECRETCODE&taskcount=" + taskcount).method(Method.GET));

   System.err.println("*** deletion task # " + taskcount + " for " + kind + " is queued.");

  }

  response.getWriter().println("OK");

 }

}
```

I have over 6 million records. That's a lot. I have no idea what the cost will be to delete the records (maybe more economical not to delete them). Another alternative would be to request a deletion for the entire application (sandbox). But that's not realistic in most cases.

I decided to go with smaller groups of records (in easy query). I know I could go for 500 entities, but then I started receiving very high rates of failure (re delete function).

***My request from GAE team: please add a feature to delete all entities of a kind in a single transaction.***

Answer (score 9):

Try using [App Engine Console](http://con.appspot.com/console/help/integration) then you dont even have to deploy any special code

Comment: There is no (AFAIK) button to delete ALL of a certain kind.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried db.delete(results) and App Engine Console, and none of them seems to be working for me. Manually removing entries from Data Viewer (increased limit up to 200) didn't work either since I have uploaded more than 10000 entries. I ended writing this script

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import wsgiref.handlers
from mainPage import YourData #replace this with your data
class CleanTable(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, param):
        txt = self.request.get('table')
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM "+txt)
        results = q.fetch(10)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        #replace yourapp and YouData your app info below.
        self.response.out.write("""
          <html>
          <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=http://yourapp.appspot.com/cleanTable?table=YourData">
            <body>""")

        try:
            for i in range(10):
                db.delete(results)
                results = q.fetch(10, len(results))
                self.response.out.write("<p>10 removed</p>")
                self.response.out.write("""
                </body>
              </html>""")

        except Exception, ints:
            self.response.out.write(str(inst))

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/cleanTable(.*)', CleanTable),
  ])

  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

The trick was to include redirect in html instead of using self.redirect. I'm ready to wait overnight to get rid of all the data in my table. Hopefully, GAE team will make it easier to drop tables in the future.

Comment: I want to adapt your solution to delete all items of one kind, with a `date` earlier than a certain `Date`. I have found a few typos in your solution, but I am worried about other typos being present b/c I don't totally understand the code. Eg, `inst` vs `ints`, how is the first `txt` value set?, what is the purpose of `5`? So if you have identified other typos please mention them. My main question is, it looks like you are deleting 100 or fewer records; can the `for` be changed to a `while db.delete(results):` by adding a `break` to the end of the `except` clause, or does that break the code?

Answer (score 5):

The fastest and efficient way to handle bulk delete on Datastore is by using the new [mapper API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) announced on the latest [Google I/O](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/).

If your language of choice is [Python](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython), you just have to register your mapper in a *mapreduce.yaml* file  and define a function like this:

```
from mapreduce import operation as op
def process(entity):
 yield op.db.Delete(entity)
```

On [Java](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava) you should have a look to [this article](http://ikaisays.com/2010/07/09/using-the-java-mapper-framework-for-app-engine/) that suggests a function like this:

```
@Override
public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context) {
    log.info("Adding key to deletion pool: " + key);
    DatastoreMutationPool mutationPool = this.getAppEngineContext(context)
            .getMutationPool();
    mutationPool.delete(value.getKey());
}
```

Comment: this is the approach I use, though it is very CPU intensive(not Datastore CPU, general CPU).

Answer (score 4):

One tip. I suggest you get to know the [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) for these types of uses (bulk deleting, modifying, etc.).  But, even with the remote api, batch size can be limited to a few hundred at a time.

Comment: Wow... that's useful, and I hadn't even heard of it. That's what I get for working mostly with the Java API which doesn't have anything similar to remote_api.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no way to easily do a bulk delete. Your best bet is to write a script that deletes a reasonable number of entries per invocation, and then call it repeatedly - for example, by having your delete script return a 302 redirect whenever there's more data to delete, then fetching it with "wget --max-redirect=10000" (or some other large number).

Comment: 302 redirects won't work, GAE limits the number of redirects per request (and also the cumulative time the request takes).

Comment: Three years too late on this comment, but that's not true and never has been: App Engine doesn't limit either of those things; browsers limit the total redirects they'll follow. App Engine does not sum up time taken over multiple requests.

Comment: Of course, my original answer is now obsolete, given the existence of mapreduce and the datastore admin console.

Answer (score 1):

With django, setup url:

```
url(r'^Model/bdelete/$', v.bulk_delete_models, {'model':'ModelKind'}),
```

Setup view

```
def bulk_delete_models(request, model):
    import time
    limit = request.GET['limit'] or 200
    start = time.clock()
    set = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM %s" % model).fetch(int(limit))
    count = len(set)
    db.delete(set)
    return HttpResponse("Deleted %s %s in %s" % (count,model,(time.clock() - start)))
```

Then run in powershell:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadString("http://your-app.com/Model/bdelete/?limit=400")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java/JPA you can do something like this:

```
    em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(entityManagerFactory)
    Query q = em.createQuery("delete from Table t");
    int number = q.executeUpdate();
```

Java/JDO info can be found here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Delete_By_Query

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:
Go to Datastore Admin, and then select the Entitiy type you want to delete and click Delete.
Mapreduce will take care of deleting!

Answer (score 1):

On a [dev server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en), one can cd to his app's directory then run it like this:

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes .
```

Doing so will start the app and clear the datastore.  If you already have another instance running, the app won't be able to bind to the needed IP and therefore fail to start...and to clear your datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task queues to delete chunks of say 100 objects.
Deleting objects in GAE shows how limited the Admin capabilities are in GAE. You have to work with batches on 1000 entities or less. You can use the bulkloader tool that works with csv's but the documentation does not cover java.
I am using GAE Java and my strategy for deletions involves having 2 servlets, one for doing the actually delete and another to load the task queues. When i want to do a delete, I run the queue loading servlet, it loads the queues and then GAE goes to work executing all the tasks in the queue.

How to do it:
Create a servlet that deletes a small number of objects.
Add the servlet to your task queues.
Go home or work on something else ;)
Check the datastore every so often ...

I have a datastore with about 5000 objects that i purge every week and it takes about 6 hours to clean out, so i run the task on Friday night.
I use the same technique to bulk load my data which happens to be about 5000 objects, with about a dozen properties.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
class ClearHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):  
    def get(self):  
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'  
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM SomeModel")  
        self.response.out.write("deleting...")  
        db.delete(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys, I got what I need. :D
This may be useful if you have lots db models to delete, you can dispatch it in your terminal. And also, you can manage the delete list in DB_MODEL_LIST yourself.
Delete DB_1:

```
python bulkdel.py 10 DB_1
```

Delete All DB:

```
python bulkdel.py 11
```

Here is the bulkdel.py file:

```
import sys, os

URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
DB_MODEL_LIST = ['DB_1', 'DB_2', 'DB_3']

# Delete Model
if sys.argv[1] == '10' :
    command = 'curl %s/clear_db?model=%s' % ( URL, sys.argv[2] )
    os.system( command )

# Delete All DB Models
if sys.argv[1] == '11' :
    for model in DB_MODEL_LIST :
        command = 'curl %s/clear_db?model=%s' % ( URL, model )
        os.system( command )
```

And here is the modified version of alexandre fiori's code.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class DBDelete( webapp.RequestHandler ):
    def get( self ):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        db_model = self.request.get('model')
        sql = 'SELECT __key__ FROM %s' % db_model

        try:
            while True:
                q = db.GqlQuery( sql )
                assert q.count()
                db.delete( q.fetch(200) )
                time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception, e:
            self.response.out.write( repr(e)+'\n' )
            pass
```

And of course, you should map the link to model in a file(like main.py in GAE), ;)
In case some guys like me need it in detail, here is part of main.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import utility # DBDelete was defined in utility.py
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/clear_db',utility.DBDelete ),('/',views.MainPage )],debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete all entities in a given kind in Google App Engine you only need to do as follows:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

query = datastore.Client().query(kind = <KIND>)
results = query.fetch()
for result in results:
    datastore.Client().delete(result.key)
```

Answer (score -2):

In javascript, the following will delete all the entries for on page:

```
document.getElementById("allkeys").checked=true;
checkAllEntities();
document.getElementById("delete_button").setAttribute("onclick","");
document.getElementById("delete_button").click();
```

given that you are on the admin-page (.../_ah/admin) with the entities you want to delete.

Comment: No, I think this does delete all the entries. This is javascript code that you can run in your browsers console to submit the right http-queries to the appengine admin pages.

Comment: Herbert's answer is a suggested way of marginally automating the browser to check the boxes and click the delete button. If one was to setup a browser automation project with Selenium or such, then this would be a legitmate but painfully slow solution to delete all entities via the admin screen as it only deletes at most 20 entities at a time.

Comment: What lalala...lambda says.

Comment: For those who downmark my answer, please provide adequate information on how to improve it. At the time I wrote the answer, the admin panel of Google App Engine did not provide functionality to delete all entries of one Entity. Since I didn't want to create an action in my source code for such administrative actions, I wrote the javascript hack to do so via the admin panel. It is ugly, but IMHO the only way to do bulk deletes without changing the application itself (since deleting in bluk might just be coincidental). So please clarify what is wrong with that idea.