# Clean datastore for GoogleAppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to clear datastore in GoogleAppEngine.

I want to clear my development data to do a test again, but I can found a way to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running from the commandline, use the --clear_datastore flag, e.g.,

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes app
```

Otherwise, if you're running it off the included GAE launcher, go into the settings of your app (double click it), and there should be a little checkbox that says "clear datastore on launch" under Launch Settings.

reference:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_the_Datastore

Answer (score 3):

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore myapp
```

assuming by "development data", you mean the data in the dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Administering Your Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html) (Experimental)

Some Other ways
[App Engine: How to "reset" the datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154811/app-engine-how-to-reset-the-datastore)

[Delete all data for a kind in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108822/delete-all-data-for-a-kind-in-google-app-engine)

Interactive console is also a great way.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, the following information can be seen in [Using the Datastore - Clearing the Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) at the end of the page (as of 2013/05/10):

> The development web server uses a local version of the Datastore for testing your application, using local files. The data persists as long as the temporary files exist, and the web server does not reset these files unless you ask it to do so.
>
> The file is named local_db.bin, and it is created in your application's WAR directory, in the WEB-INF/appengine-generated/ directory. To clear the Datastore, delete this file.

So, stop your server, delete the file, and restart it up.

Answer (score -1):

On your local machine you can go to : `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore`