# how to delete multiple data using check box in google app engine (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google app engine, how can i delete multiple data selected in check box. For a sample i had attached the image below. here i had selected the multiple check boxes and the data shown are stored in the Google app engine.

[image: Sample check box]

i have my jsp code for check box like this,

```
<input name="delete" type="checkbox"/>
```

can anyone suggest me how to select the data and delete it from Google app engine.

**Edited:**
For storing the data i used,

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 Entity employee = new Entity("Employee");
 employee.setProperty("First Name", fname);
 datastore.put(employee);
```

For retrieving the data i used,

```
 Query query = new Query("Employee");
 List<Entity> emp = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(20));
 for (Entity user : emp){
 // inside the table 
  user.getProperty("File Name")}
```

By this i can retrieve the data.

Comment: We will need to know how you store data in GAE. How do you select the data that you show?

Comment: @Ian Marshall i had added the storing and retrieving of data from GAE.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<input type="checkbox"...>` as checkbox?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen i changed it. i can pass the "delete" as request parameter but i dont know how to delete it from datastore. Any advice pls

Comment: Are you using just plain JSP or any framework?

Comment: just plain jsp and servlet thats it..

Comment: I recommend [Stripes Framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home), which is very lightweight, convenient and runs nicely on appengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend that you use two frameworks to make your life easier:

- [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home)
- [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)

OK, here you go: I'm not sure to which degree your question is a basic JSP/Servlet question or a specific Appengine question. However, you have to do the follwoing:

- Have a list of checkboxes on your JSP page, like this: `<stripes:checkbox name="employees[${loop.index}].id" value="${employee.id}"/>` (see: http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Indexed+Properties)
- Pass a list of IDs (of the entities that should be deleted) to the Servlet.
- Delete the entities based on these IDs.
- Here's the catch: Appengine can terminate the request before all entities are deleted. That can happen if the request takes too long. Therefore you should delete the entities asynchronously, using chunks of data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882697/1277252) for further information.