# Inexpensive/free way to delete a kind from datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have about 8.8 million entities for a particular kind. They take up 5GB of space.
The built-in indexes for this kind take up 50GB of space.

I did some tests, and deleting 100k entries produces over a million data store write operations.

Since datastore writes cost ~$1 for a million ops, it looks like it will cost me at least $100 to delete this kind.

Is there any shortcut to doing this?  I did try using the built-in mapreduce 'delete' in the appengine interface, but it started burning through my daily quota quite fast so I stopped it.

So the question is: is there any inexpensive/free way to delete a kind that I am missing?

-s

Comment: What if you would do it slowly, only a limited number per day? You could queue a task in the taskqueue which would delete only a few then would queue a new task with some countdown...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all data for a kind in Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108822/delete-all-data-for-a-kind-in-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

[Enable the Datastore Admin feature](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Enable_datastore_admin) in your GAE app. Once it's enabled open Datastore Admin in the Admin Console. Among other things it allows you to [bulk delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk) all entities of a kind. While [Google says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Deleting_entities_in_bulk_via_the_Administration_Console):

> Caution: This feature is currently experimental. We believe it is the fastest way to bulk-delete data, but it is not yet stable and you may encounter occasional bugs.

.. they don't say what the pricing on bulk delete is. It *might* be the same as for Datastore Writes. If it is then [100k ops will cost $0.09](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/) resulting in a total cost of **$0.09 / 100,000 * 8,800,000 = $7.92**.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that, thanks though. "I did try using the built-in mapreduce 'delete' in the appengine interface..." <-- That's the Datastore Admin feature Delete operation

Comment: What is your daily quota? What did it cost you?